# how many possible ways to have a 5 digit code with 3 different numbers and two identical letters?

Tags: combinatorics

On a keyboard 1-9 and A-D , how many possible way to have a 5 digit code with 3 different numbers and two identical letters (order isn't a problem)?

My try : 9C3 x 4C1 = 84 x 4 = 336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to select 3 different numbers and essentially 1 letter (as selecting the first letter will result in selecting the second).

Since order doesn't matter, all possible combinations can be written in the form NNNLL, where N is number and L is letter.

The possible ways of doing this are:
$${9 \choose 3}\times{4 \choose 1} =336$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\color{red}9$ numbers and $\color{blue}4$ letters to choose from.

We have to choose $3$ different numbers among the $\color{red}9$ we have. The number of possible combinations can easily be computed with $\binom{\color{red}9}{3}$.

Use an analogous approach for the letters.

---

My *result*

> $$\binom{\color{red}9}{3}\cdot\binom{\color{blue}{4}}{{1}}=\fbox{336}$$

Comment: There was a typo...